# Determine all eigenvalues for L

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Consider the function
\begin{align}
L : P_3(\mathbb{R}) & \rightarrow P_3(\mathbb{R}) \\
p & \mapsto p' + p
\end{align}
where $p'$ is the differential quotient of the reel polynomium $p \in P_3(\mathbb{R})$. Then I have to determine all eigenvalues for $L$.

As I have given a linear operator, which I have proved $L$ is, I have to pick a basis for $\mathcal{V} = (1,X,X^2)$ for $P_3(\mathbb{R})$. Then I have to calculate the SMR for L which means that I have to calculate
$$
[L(1)]_{\mathcal{V}} = (1,0,0)^T
$$
$$
[L(X)]_{\mathcal{V}} = (-1,1,0)^T
$$
$$
[L(X^2)]_{\mathcal{V}} = (0,-2,1)^T
$$
but I simply do not understand why we get minus in the two last ones. Should it be $(1,1,0)^T$ and $(0,2,1)^T$. The ones I wrote first are the ones my TA has calculated so we can check if we are doing it correctly, but I don't understand where the minus comes from. Can you please very which ones are correct and why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have to use a matrix representation to solve this? The eigenvalues of $L$ can be found pretty directly by noting that differentiation reduces the degree of a polynomial, so the only possible eigenvalue is $1$. Verifying that it is an eigenvalue is then pretty simple. On the other hand, the matrix of $L$ is triangular, so the eigenvalues are readily apparent once you have the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct. If one assumes the standard basis for $P_3(\mathbb{R})$, then the representations corresponding to $L(X) = 1 + X$ and $L(X^2) = 2X + X^2$ are $(1, 1, 0)$ and $(0, 2, 1)$, respectively.

Comment: Thank you very much, Jan! :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the title, you don't need coordinates:
$ L(p) = \lambda p$ iff $p'=(\lambda-1)p$.
By comparing degrees, the only solution is $p'=0$ with $\lambda=1$.